# Съезжает текст на изображении css/html

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Всем привет!
Подскажите пожалуйста, есть картинка на главной страничке и на ней нужно написать текст из 2 предложений. Написать, написал через position: absolute; Но адаптивностью здесь и не пахнет, не могу разобраться. Подскажите пожалуйста
Надо чтобы при уменьшении разрешения, уменьшался текст и картинка

```css
img {
  position: relative;
}
h2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  Color: #ffff;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://s00.yaplakal.com/pics/pics_original/5/6/2/10439265.jpg" alt="Баннер" class="img">
<h2>Hello world!</h2>
```

Comment: Вы хотите чтобы текст уменьшался пропорционально изображению?

Comment: @MaxWatson ага, а то текст становится больше, а изображение уменьшается

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте поместил изображение как background для div в котором будет текст. 
По уменьшению текста. Для этого используют медиа запросы и в каждом указать нужный font-size

Comment: @MaxWatson, ага, сделал под 3 разрешения все получилось. Спс за лайфхак)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать так..

```css
img {
  position: relative;
}
h2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  Color: #ffff;
  font-size: calc(3vw + 3vh);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://s00.yaplakal.com/pics/pics_original/5/6/2/10439265.jpg" alt="Баннер" class="img">
<h2>Hello world!</h2>
```

Comment: оО, гениально! сенк)

Comment: На здоровье! :)