# Как автоматически подогнать размер шрифта, чтобы он полностью заполнял контейнер и зависел от высоты контейнера?

Tags: javascript, css3, вёрстка

У меня есть блок с фиксированной высотой и предполагается из админки вставлять в этот блок текст разной длины.
Мне необходимо, чтобы этот текст полностью помещался в контейнер и не выходил за высоту блока, чтобы автоматически назначался определенный размер шрифта.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно решить эту проблему, может есть какая-то библиотека для этого?

пример, как должен подстраиваться шрифт

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасибо за любой совет

```
ссылка на песочницу
```

https://codepen.io/IvanGrishov/pen/KKoMNro

Comment: Посмотри [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1372775/%d0%a1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-css-html/1372786#1372786)

Comment: здесь размер зависит от высоты и ширины окна браузера, а не от родительского контейнера.